# Akka: How to wrap a message content into an HTTP response?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-http

In my Akka-http route I get a specific message back and I want to wrap its content as error message like:

```
val response:Future[T] = (actor ? command).mapTo[T]
    response match {
      case err : Future[InvalidRequest] => 
          HttpResponse(408, entity = err.map(_.toJson).????)
      case r : Future[T] => r.map(_.toJson)
    }

case class InvalidRequest(error:String)

implicit val invalidRequestFormat = jsonFormat1(InvalidRequest)
```

but that doesn't work. How can I map it as text in json format?

Comment: Are you using Akka's spray json support for your marshaling to json?

Comment: yes I have updated the question

Comment: I think it might be easier just trying to change the http status to 408

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I can provide a generic solution for what it is you are trying to do.  You can start by creating a method that returns a `Route` as follows:

```
def service[T:ClassTag](actor:ActorRef, command:Any)
 (implicit timeout:Timeout,  _marshaller: ToResponseMarshaller[T]):Route = {
  val fut = (actor ? command).mapTo[ServiceResponse]
  onComplete(fut){
    case util.Success(ir:InvalidRequest) =>
      complete(StatusCodes.BadRequest, ir)

    case util.Success(t:T) =>
      complete(t)

    case util.Failure(ex) =>
      complete(StatusCodes.InternalServerError )        
  }    
}
```

This method fires a request to a supplied actor, via ask, and gets the `Future` representing the result.  It then uses the `onComplete` directive to apply special handling to the `InvalidResponse` case.  It's important here that you have an implicit `ToResponseMarshaller[T]` in scope as you will need that for the success case.

Then, let's say you had the following classes and formatters defined:

```
trait ServiceResponse
case class Foo(id:Int) extends ServiceResponse
implicit val fooFormat = jsonFormat1(Foo)
case class InvalidRequest(error:String) extends ServiceResponse
implicit val invalidRequestFormat = jsonFormat1(InvalidRequest)
```

You could use your new `service` method within your routing tree as follows:

```
val routes:Route = {
  path("api" / "foo"){
    get{
      service[Foo](fooActor, FooActor.DoFoo)
    }
  }  
}
```

The problem with your example is that you were not waiting for the completion of the `Future` before building out the response.  You were trying to match on the underlying type of the `Future`, which is eliminated by erasure at runtime, so is not a good idea to try and match against in that way.  You instead need to wait until it's completed and then see the type that is behind the `Future`.

Comment: Thank you. I am using Akka 2.4.7 and the only valid signature for `complete` is `def complete(m: ⇒ ToResponseMarshallable)` so I cannot inject the status.

Comment: @Randomize, any chance you can bump up to Akka 2.4.8?

Comment: yes I did it. However it was just doing this: `complete(StatusCodes.BadRequest, ir.error)`